# How to $.extend 2 objects by adding numerical values together from keys with the same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have 2 obj and using the jquery extend function, however it's overriding value from keys with the same name. How can I add the values together instead?

```
var obj1 = {
  "orange": 2,
  "apple": 1,
  "grape": 1
};

var obj2 = {
  "orange": 5,
  "apple": 1,
  "banana": 1
};

mergedObj = $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);

var printObj = typeof JSON != "undefined" ? JSON.stringify : function (obj) {
  var arr = [];

  $.each(obj, function (key, val) {
    var next = key + ": ";
    next += $.isPlainObject(val) ? printObj(val) : val;
    arr.push(next);
  });

  return "{ " + arr.join(", ") + " }";
};

console.log('all together: ' + printObj(mergedObj));
```

And I get `obj1 = {"orange":5,"apple":1, "grape":1, "banana":1}`

What I need is  `obj1 = {"orange":7,"apple":2, "grape":1, "banana":1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `$.extend` does is join the two objects but it doesn't add the values, it **overrides** them.
You're going to have to do this manually. `$.extend` will be useful to add or modify fruits to your object but if you need the total sum you gonna have to loop:

```
var obj1 = { orange: 2, apple: 1, grape: 1 };
var obj2 = { orange: 5, apple: 1, banana: 1 };
var result = $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
for (var o in result) {
  result[o] = (obj1[o] || 0) + (obj2[o] || 0);
}
console.log(result); //=> { orange: 7, apple: 2, grape: 1, banana: 1 }
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/emGyb/

Answer (score 4):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/69fja/)

That's not how `.extend()` works; you'll have to implement your own:

```
function mergeObjects() {
    var mergedObj = arguments[0] || {};
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var obj = arguments[i];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if( obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
                if( mergedObj[key] ) {
                    mergedObj[key] += obj[key];
                }
                else {
                    mergedObj[key] = obj[key];
                }
            }                
        }
    }
    return mergedObj;
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj1 = { "orange": 2, "apple": 1, "grape": 1 };
var obj2 = { "orange": 5, "apple": 1, "banana": 1 };
var mergedObj = mergeObjects( obj1, obj2);
// mergedObj {"orange":7,"apple":2,"grape":1,"banana":1}
```

Of course, like `.extend()`, this will work with any number of objects -- not just 2.

Comment: Very nice, straight JS too I like it!

Comment: If you want to make it somewhat match the jquery functionality, they effectively do (using your code above) `mergedObject = arguments[0] || {}`

Comment: @anthony Thanks, that's definitely a more efficient way of doing it, I updated my code above :)

Comment: Note that this will alter your `obj1` : when hitting `var mergedObj = arguments[0] || {};`, `mergedObj` becomes `obj1`.

To avoid this, initialize `mergedObj` with `{}` and start the loop at 0.

Comment: @Owumaro That's intentional, to match the [`$.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) functionality, as pointed out in the comment above. As the docs state, it "*[merges] the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.*" If that's not desired you can modify it as you suggested, of course. Thanks for calling that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you could use:

```
obj1 = {"orange":2,"apple":1, "grape":1};
obj2 = {"orange":5,"apple":1, "banana":1};
var joined = {};

// add numbers in arr to joined
function addItems(arr) {

    // cycle through the keys in the array
    for (var x in arr) {

        // get the existing value or create it as zero, then add the new value
        joined[x] = (joined[x] || 0) + arr[x];
    }
}

addItems(obj1);
addItems(obj2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(joined));
```

*Output:*

> {"orange":7,"apple":2,"grape":1,"banana":1}

Answer (score 0):

No fancy stuff, just simple Javascript:

The `c[k] || 0` is there in the event that `c[k]` has no value, it gets to be zero.

```
var a = {orange:2, apple:1, grape:1};
var b = {orange:5, apple:1, banana:1};
var c = {};
var k;

for (k in a)  {c[k] = 0 + a[k] + (c[k] || 0)}
for (k in b)  {c[k] = 0 + b[k] + (c[k] || 0)}


window.alert(JSON.stringify(c));
```